# Can i only write the class name, not the full name in the output template?

Tags: serilog

This is my logging config:

```json
{
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
        "System": "Warning",
        "System.Net.Http.HttpClient": "Warning",
        "Hangfire": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
          "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj} {SourceContext}{NewLine}{Exception}"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "%CUROUTDIR%\\..\\Logs\\%PROCESSNAME%\\%PROCESSNAME% .txt",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true,
          "retainedFileCountLimit": 31,
          "fileSizeLimitBytes": 5242880,
          "outPutTemplate": "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj} {Properties:j}{NewLine}{Exception}"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And this produces results like:

```
[16:31:44 INF] WebHostApplicationBootstrapper`1 Init end in 00:00:03.7921289 OPG.Foundation.GenericHostApplicationBootstrapper
[16:31:44 WRN] Environment: Development OPG.Foundation.GenericHostApplicationBootstrapper
[16:31:46 FTL] Sensitive data logging is enabled. Log entries and exception messages may include sensitive application data; this mode should only be enabled during development. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation
[16:31:49 INF] Now listening on: https://localhost:5001 Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime
[16:31:49 INF] Now listening on: http://localhost:5000 Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime
```

As you can see the source context is added to the output template just fine, but it shows the complete full name of the class, including assembly and so on.

For the console this causes a bit too much clutter for my taste - could i somehow only display the class name instead of the fullname for the source context?

Comment: I suspect this is a dup but... you can use an enricher to either replace the SourceContext or add a variant of it and reference that file instead, or use Serilog.Expressions - google it and you'll hit a blog post with examples of things it can do

Comment: googling it (as always) brings the stackoverflow post where it is recommended that we should google it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this using [Serilog.Expressions](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-expressions) and a computed property:

```
.Enrich.WithComputed("SourceContextName", "Substring(SourceContext, LastIndexOf(SourceContext, '.') + 1)")
```

Which can then be used in the output template:

````
"[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3} {SourceContextName}]: {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"```
````

You could also just include the Substring-expression directly in your output template if you don't need the property for other purposes (queries in Seq f.ex).

Answer (score 0):

I had a wrinkle on this scenario, where some of my `SourceContext` entries were generic classes and contained periods later in the the output string for dll version strings from the implemented class; this code ended up doing the trick for me:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
             .Enrich.FromLogContext()
             .Enrich.WithComputed("SourceContextWithoutDll", "Substring(SourceContext, 0, if LastIndexOf(SourceContext, '`') > 0 then LastIndexOf(SourceContext, '`') else Length(SourceContext))")
             .Enrich.WithComputed("SourceContextName", "Substring(SourceContextWithoutDll, LastIndexOf(SourceContextWithoutDll, '.') + 1)")
             .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
             .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {SourceContextName} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}")
             .CreateLogger();
```